# I have a long table and wants to divide it into pages,

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, threeparttable, page

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{cccc}
    \toprule
    & fddummy & fddummy & \multicolumn{1}{l}{fddummy} \\
    \midrule
    Grey  &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
    nwcr  & -3.482*** & -3.450*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-3.479***} \\
    & (0.777) & (0.786) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.785)} \\
    cacl  & -0.201 & -0.222 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.213} \\
    & (0.218) & (0.222) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.222)} \\
    fl    & -0.920 & -0.936 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.936} \\
    & (0.756) & (0.758) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.760)} \\
    clnw  & 0.000 & 0.000 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.000} \\
    & (0.000) & (0.000) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.000)} \\
    opta  & -25.701*** & -25.918*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-25.699***} \\
    & (5.901) & (5.968) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(5.964)} \\
    roe   & 0.027 & 0.030 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.031} \\
    & (0.035) & (0.037) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.037)} \\
    roa   & 21.812*** & 21.662*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{21.434***} \\
    & (6.132) & (6.199) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(6.196)} \\
    sg    & -0.002 & -0.002 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.002} \\
    & (0.005) & (0.004) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.004)} \\
    cftl  & -0.150 & -0.127 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.152} \\
    & (0.729) & (0.731) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.733)} \\
    cfotl & -1.943*** & -1.938*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-1.920***} \\
    & (0.725) & (0.725) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.726)} \\
    cfitl & -2.279*** & -2.130** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-2.122**} \\
    & (0.829) & (0.837) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.837)} \\
    sz    & -0.203*** & -0.224*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.219***} \\
    & (0.059) & (0.060) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.061)} \\
    ope   & 0.045 & -0.016 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.013} \\
    & (0.145) & (0.148) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.149)} \\
    infg  &       & 0.164 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.170} \\
    &       & (0.215) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.215)} \\
    gdpg  &       & 0.316 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.327} \\
    &       & (0.254) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.255)} \\
    exchg &       & -0.558 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-1.299} \\
    &       & (1.598) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(1.962)} \\
    uneg  &       & 0.373* & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.429*} \\
    &       & (0.201) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.219)} \\
    fcdummy &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.157} \\
    &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.243)} \\
    \_cons & 3.243*** & 3.563*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.475***} \\
    & (0.975) & (1.009) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(1.024)} \\
    Distressed &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
    nwcr  & -5.338*** & -5.233*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-5.165***} \\
    & (0.964) & (0.971) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.972)} \\
    cacl  & -1.719*** & -1.788*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-1.807***} \\
    & (0.461) & (0.463) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.463)} \\
    fl    & -2.223** & -2.177** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-2.148**} \\
    & (1.007) & (1.001) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.997)} \\
    clnw  & -0.000 & -0.000 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.000} \\
    & (0.000) & (0.000) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.000)} \\
    opta  & -27.617*** & -28.474*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-28.891***} \\
    & (6.207) & (6.319) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(6.353)} \\
    roe   & -0.032 & -0.026 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.027} \\
    & (0.054) & (0.053) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.053)} \\
    roa   & 18.797*** & 19.367*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{19.792***} \\
    & (6.462) & (6.568) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(6.600)} \\
    sg    & 0.001 & 0.001 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.001} \\
    & (0.001) & (0.001) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.001)} \\
    cftl  & -0.867 & -0.713 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.667} \\
    & (0.908) & (0.890) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.891)} \\
    cfotl & -4.171*** & -4.295*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-4.317***} \\
    & (1.018) & (1.021) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(1.019)} \\
    cfitl & -0.761 & -0.575 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.571} \\
    & (0.802) & (0.700) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.709)} \\
    sz    & -0.065 & -0.081 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.088} \\
    & (0.066) & (0.068) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.068)} \\
    ope   & 0.130 & 0.057 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.047} \\
    & (0.170) & (0.174) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.174)} \\
    infg  &       & -0.061 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.065} \\
    &       & (0.239) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.240)} \\
    gdpg  &       & 0.259 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.250} \\
    &       & (0.279) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.279)} \\
    exchg &       & -0.515 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.517} \\
    &       & (1.735) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(2.051)} \\
    uneg  &       & 0.410* & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.335} \\
    &       & (0.221) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.235)} \\
    fcdummy &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-0.243} \\
    &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(0.263)} \\
    \_cons & 2.796** & 3.110*** & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.261***} \\
    & (1.118) & (1.150) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{(1.163)} \\
    N     & 1714  & 1705  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1705} \\
    pseudo R-sq & 0.292 & 0.295 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.296} \\
    \midrule
    Standard errors in parentheses &       &       &  \\
    * p<0.1 &  ** p<0.05 &  *** p<0.01" &  \\

\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: use `longtable` not `tabularx` also please always post a complete small document not just a fragment.

Comment: I am a new user and actually, I do not know how to use latex, im facing a big problem with long table.

Comment: I have use longtable but it showing many errors.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It could be refined more but this will get you started

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{@{}l D..{4.4} D..{4.4} D..{4.4} D..{4.4}@{}}
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{fddummy} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{fddummy} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{fddummy} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    Grey  &       &       &  \\
    nwcr  & -3.482\rlap{$^{***}$} & -3.450\rlap{$^{***}$} & -3.479\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (0.777) & (0.786) & (0.785) \\
    cacl  & -0.201 & -0.222 & -0.213 \\
    & (0.218) & (0.222) & (0.222) \\
    fl    & -0.920 & -0.936 & -0.936 \\
    & (0.756) & (0.758) & (0.760) \\
    clnw  & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
    & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
    opta  & -25.701\rlap{$^{***}$} & -25.918\rlap{$^{***}$} & -25.699\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (5.901) & (5.968) & (5.964) \\
    roe   & 0.027 & 0.030 & 0.031 \\
    & (0.035) & (0.037) & (0.037) \\
    roa   & 21.812\rlap{$^{***}$} & 21.662\rlap{$^{***}$} & 21.434\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (6.132) & (6.199) & (6.196) \\
    sg    & -0.002 & -0.002 & -0.002 \\
    & (0.005) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\
    cftl  & -0.150 & -0.127 & -0.152 \\
    & (0.729) & (0.731) & (0.733) \\
    cfotl & -1.943\rlap{$^{***}$} & -1.938\rlap{$^{***}$} & -1.920\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (0.725) & (0.725) & (0.726) \\
    cfitl & -2.279\rlap{$^{***}$} & -2.130\rlap{$^{**}$} & -2.122\rlap{$^{**}$} \\
    & (0.829) & (0.837) & (0.837) \\
    sz    & -0.203\rlap{$^{***}$} & -0.224\rlap{$^{***}$} & -0.219\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (0.059) & (0.060) & (0.061) \\
    ope   & 0.045 & -0.016 & -0.013 \\
    & (0.145) & (0.148) & (0.149) \\
    infg  &       & 0.164 & 0.170 \\
    &       & (0.215) & (0.215) \\
    gdpg  &       & 0.316 & 0.327 \\
    &       & (0.254) & (0.255) \\
    exchg &       & -0.558 & -1.299 \\
    &       & (1.598) & (1.962) \\
    uneg  &       & 0.373\rlap{$^{*}$} & 0.429\rlap{$^{*}$} \\
    &       & (0.201) & (0.219) \\
    fcdummy &       &       & 0.157 \\
    &       &       & (0.243) \\
    \_cons & 3.243\rlap{$^{***}$} & 3.563\rlap{$^{***}$} & 3.475\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (0.975) & (1.009) & (1.024) \\
    Distressed &       &       &  \\
    nwcr  & -5.338\rlap{$^{***}$} & -5.233\rlap{$^{***}$} & -5.165\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (0.964) & (0.971) & (0.972) \\
    cacl  & -1.719\rlap{$^{***}$} & -1.788\rlap{$^{***}$} & -1.807\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (0.461) & (0.463) & (0.463) \\
    fl    & -2.223\rlap{$^{**}$} & -2.177\rlap{$^{**}$} & -2.148\rlap{$^{**}$} \\
    & (1.007) & (1.001) & (0.997) \\
    clnw  & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 \\
    & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
    opta  & -27.617\rlap{$^{***}$} & -28.474\rlap{$^{***}$} & -28.891\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (6.207) & (6.319) & (6.353) \\
    roe   & -0.032 & -0.026 & -0.027 \\
    & (0.054) & (0.053) & (0.053) \\
    roa   & 18.797\rlap{$^{***}$} & 19.367\rlap{$^{***}$} & 19.792\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (6.462) & (6.568) & (6.600) \\
    sg    & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 \\
    & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\
    cftl  & -0.867 & -0.713 & -0.667 \\
    & (0.908) & (0.890) & (0.891) \\
    cfotl & -4.171\rlap{$^{***}$} & -4.295\rlap{$^{***}$} & -4.317\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (1.018) & (1.021) & (1.019) \\
    cfitl & -0.761 & -0.575 & -0.571 \\
    & (0.802) & (0.700) & (0.709) \\
    sz    & -0.065 & -0.081 & -0.088 \\
    & (0.066) & (0.068) & (0.068) \\
    ope   & 0.130 & 0.057 & 0.047 \\
    & (0.170) & (0.174) & (0.174) \\
    infg  &       & -0.061 & -0.065 \\
    &       & (0.239) & (0.240) \\
    gdpg  &       & 0.259 & 0.250 \\
    &       & (0.279) & (0.279) \\
    exchg &       & -0.515 & 0.517 \\
    &       & (1.735) & (2.051) \\
    uneg  &       & 0.410* & 0.335 \\
    &       & (0.221) & (0.235) \\
    fcdummy &       &       & -0.243 \\
    &       &       & (0.263) \\
    \_cons & 2.796\rlap{$^{**}$} & 3.110\rlap{$^{***}$} & 3.261\rlap{$^{***}$} \\
    & (1.118) & (1.150) & (1.163) \\
    N     & 1714  & 1705  & 1705 \\
    pseudo R-sq & 0.292 & 0.295 & 0.296 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Standard errors in parentheses}\\
    \rlap{$^{*}$} p<0.1 &  \rlap{$^{**}$} p<0.05 &  \rlap{$^{***}$} p<0.01" &  
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much.